# How to allocate the memory for b in LAPACK sgelsd routine

Tags: lapack, lapacke

According to the official user guide line, sgelsd is used to solve the least square problem

```
min_x || b - Ax ||_2
```

and allows matrix A to be rectangle and rank-deficient. And according to the interface description in the sgelsd source code, b is used as input-output parameter. When sgelsd is finished, b stores the solution. So b occupies m*sizeof(float) bytes. While the solution x needs n*sizeof(float) bytes (assume A is a m*n matrix, and b is a m*1 vector).

However, when n>m, the memory of b is too small to store the solution x. How to deal with this situation? I did not get it from the comments of sgelsd source code. Can I just allocate n*sizeof(float) bytes for b and use the first m*sizeof(float) to store the b vector?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [example from Intel MKL](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/mkl_sa/11/mkl_lapack_examples/sgelsd_ex.c.htm) has the answer.  B is allocated as LDB*NRHS (LDB = max(M,N), and zero-padded.  Note that the input B is not necessarily a 1-vector, SGELSD can handle multiple least-squares problems at the same time (hence NRHS).

From the [Lapack docs for SGELSD](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d0/db8/group__real_g_esolve.html#gabc655f9cb0f6cfff81b3cafc03c41dcb):

> [in,out]  B
>
> ```
>       B is REAL array, dimension (LDB,NRHS)
>       On entry, the M-by-NRHS right hand side matrix B.
>       On exit, B is overwritten by the N-by-NRHS solution
>       matrix X.  If m >= n and RANK = n, the residual
>       sum-of-squares for the solution in the i-th column is given
>       by the sum of squares of elements n+1:m in that column.
> ```
>
> [in]  LDB
>
> ```
>       LDB is INTEGER
>       The leading dimension of the array B. LDB >= max(1,max(M,N)).
> ```